# Visual Studio VB Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I have button update and the code

```
Private Sub txtSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSave.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TrackingBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.InventoryDataSet)
        MsgBox("Record Update")
End Sub
```

When run, I got error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.'
```

Not sure do I miss something for update records. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a typed `DataSet` from a database, the wizard generates a `DataTable` and a table adapter for each database table. The `DataTable` schema is based on the table schema, as is the SQL in the commands of the table adapter.

The `SelectCommand` contains a `SELECT` statement that will retrieve all columns of all rows and is executed when you call `Fill`. The `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` contain `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements respectively and are executed as required when you call `Update`.

The `SelectCommand` and `InsertCommand` can always be generated because all they need to know is the name and data type of each column. `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements need to be able to identify the specific record to update or delete and they do that by specifying the primary key value in the `WHERE` clause. If your database table has no primary key then that SQL cannot be generated and your table adapter will have no `UpdateCommand` or `DeleteCommand`.

What you need to do is to make sure that all your database tables have a primary key. It can be valid to have a table without a PK but it is very rare. Once your table has a PK, you can re-run the Data Source wizard to update your typed `DataSet`. There is a button on the toolbar in the Data Sources window to do that.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know about Primary Key is needed.